Bitcoin learning games?
I'm seeking ideas for very simple games involving sending/receiving Testnet Bitcoin?
I'm gathering some noobs to show them how to send/receive bitcoin.
Once we issue a coupla transactions, I was thinking it might be fun to turn it into a game to increase the learning.
We're using Blockstream Green wallet to do this because it has an easy option for Testnet (thank you to r/Bitcoin for teaching me this).
I'm prepared to send Testnet Bitcoin by virtue of these faucets:
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Testnet#Faucets

Padawan Wallet seems very fitting to your usecase, from the website:

Padawan is application is a place to learn the common features of mobile bitcoin wallets.
It uses bitcoin’s testnet, an alternative bitcoin network used
globally and built exclusively for testing. The coins on this network
do not have any value, but they otherwise look and behave just like
normal bitcoins!
This wallet is built for users of all ages to experiment and learn
about bitcoin in a risk-free environment.

https://padawanwallet.com/
Regarding games, you could try to play board games for testnet coins, Poker for example.

Padawan looks interesting but it's not available for iOS phones, just Android.
